# create roles for different users on mongodb version 2.4.9

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongohq

I'm new to mongodb , and i'm trying to understand and how to grant access to the users of my database ( i have a mongodb data base from mongoHQ sandbox 512 Mb free ).

after connecting to my mongodb from my [mongo shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo)

i have a database named **event** and it contains 2 collections

- **message**
- **provider**

i created 2 users :

- messageUser
- providerUser

what i want is :

- **messageUser** only can read **message** collection , and hasn't access to read,write on **provider** collection
- **providerUser** only privileges to read,write on **provider** collection and read privilege on **message** collection

I found [db.addUser() - Version 2.4.9](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/) but i cannot define privileges on collections

**example** ( after successfully connected to mongodb from mongo shell ) :

```
use event
db.addUser( { user: "messageUser", pwd: "password", roles: ["read"] } )
```

but messageUser stil have access to read **provider** collection

but i found on the latest version 2.6.x 
db.addUser : [http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.addUser/#db.addUser] and 
db.createRole: [http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.createRole/#db.createRole]
we can define more 'sophisticated privileges' for example :
grant privileges **messageUser** to only **find** action on **message** collection's 
Privilege Action : [http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/privilege-actions/]

```
db.addUser({
    user: 'messageUser',
    pwd: 'password',
    privileges: [{
                resource: {collection: "messages" },
                actions: [ "find"]
            }],
    roles: [ "read"]
 });
```

also i find that we can define user privileges from adding users to the database named **amin**
unfortunately **MongoHQ** service doesn't give permission to access on this database

please ask more information if needed or if there something not clearly explained 
it will be very useful if i get some useful responses very quickly

Thank you

Dinesh

Comment: You are correct that 2.4 MongoDB only allows DB level privileges while in 2.6 will be resource level privileges which allows for collection level privileges. You could try this on the release candidates of 2.6 but I would not use them for production. I'm not familiar with MongoHQ but it looks like this question would be best asked directly to their support team.